# Inbreeding depression and dominance

Tags: evolution, molecular-genetics, population-dynamics, population-biology, molecular-evolution

From [this article](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.es.18.110187.001321?journalCode=ecolsys.1),  second paragraph of the second page

> A classic theoretical result is that the mean of a character controlled by a single locus ***i*** with two alleles ***A<sub>i1</sub>*** and ***A<sub>i2</sub>*** is only affected by the value of ***f*** if there is some degree of dominance.

where ***f*** is the Wright's inbreeding coefficient.

The authors then add:

> Assume that the trait is scaled such that the values for the genotypes ***A<sub>i1</sub>A<sub>i1</sub>***, ***A<sub>i1</sub>A<sub>i2</sub>***, and ***A<sub>i2</sub>A<sub>i2</sub>*** are ***-a<sub>i</sub>***, ***d<sub>i</sub>***, and ***a<sub>i</sub>*** respectively. The quantities ***a<sub>i</sub>*** and ***d<sub>i</sub>*** measure the effect of the locus on the character and the degree of dominance of the locus, respectively. With two alleles, there is a linear decline in the mean of a trait
>   with increasing ***f*** either with overdominance (***d<sub>i</sub>*** > ***a<sub>i</sub>***) or if the allele associated with an increased value of the trait is dominant or partially dominant (***a<sub>i</sub>*** ≥ ***d<sub>i</sub>*** > ***0***). With additive joint effects of different loci on the trait, this conclusion can be extended to a polygenic character; inbreeding decline occurs if the average value of ***d<sub>i</sub>*** over all ***i*** is positive.

I don't understand why "[..] there is a linear decline in the mean of a trait
with increasing ***f*** either with overdominance (***d<sub>i</sub>*** > ***a<sub>i</sub>***) or if the allele associated with an increased value of the trait is dominant or partially dominant (***a<sub>i</sub>*** ≥ ***d<sub>i</sub>*** > ***0***)"

Can you please explain why the mean of a character controlled by a single locus is only affected by the value of ***"f"*** if there is some degree of dominance.

Comment: man i should be able to answer this. i didnt take that class though. I could write a doctor who knows the answer but i doubt he would respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Recap of the question:**

Looking at a single locus trait ($A$) controlled by two alleles, $A_1$ and $A_2$, the phenotypic mean is only affected by inbreeding depression, $f$ (Wright's inbreeding coefficient), if there is some degree of dominance, $d$. Why?

**Answer:**

If we take inbreeding as a higher than expected frequency of homozygotes, such that if the frequencies of alleles $A_1$ and $A_2$ are $p = q = 0.5$ the expected frequencies of the genotypes in an outbred population, $P_{outbred}$, would be $p^2 = 0.25$, $2pq = 0.50$, and $q^2 = 0.25$.

Each genotype has the following phenotypic result on a trait $A_1A_1 = 5$, $A_1A_2 = 7.5$, $A_2A_2 = 10$... this is an additive trait with allele $A_1$ having an additive effect of 2.5, and $A_2$ an additive effect of 5.

We can then compare an inbred population of 100 individuals, $P_{inbred}$ where the frequency of $A_1A_1 = 0.5$, $A_1A_2 = 0$, $A2_A2 = 0.5$, to $P_{outbred}$ , where I use $\bar{X}$ to symbolise trait means.

$\bar{X}_{inbred} = \frac{(50 \cdot 5) + (0 \cdot 7.5) + (50 \cdot 10)}{100} = 7.5$

$\bar{X}_{outbred} = \frac{(25 \cdot 5) + (50 \cdot 7.5) + (25 \cdot 10)}{100} = 7.5$

So when the trait is additive the population means are equal. It is onlt when we add dominance to the situation that the population means will differ as a result of inbreeding. Continuing from the above example, the populations are the same size and structure, but $A_2$ is now completely dominant to $A_1$ such that $A_1A_2$ individuals now have a trait value of 10. Now

$\bar{X}_{inbred} = \frac{(50 \cdot 5) + (0 \cdot 10) + (50 \cdot 10)}{100} = 7.5$

$\bar{X}_{outbred} = \frac{(25 \cdot 5) + (50 \cdot 10) + (25 \cdot 10)}{100} = 8.75$

Thus inbreeding has affected the population mean in a trait which has dominance, it is basically because the heterozygotes are less common in an inbreeding population and this is where dominance effects are seen.

> "there is a linear decline in the mean of a trait with increasing f... with overdominance (di > ai)"

This is because in the case of overdominance, the outbred population mean becomes even more elevated - if we say now the $A_1A2$ trait is a phenotype of 15 the means become

$\bar{X}_{inbred} = \frac{(50 \cdot 5) + (0 \cdot 15) + (50 \cdot 10)}{100} = 7.5$

$\bar{X}_{outbred} = \frac{(25 \cdot 5) + (50 \cdot 15) + (25 \cdot 10)}{100} = 11.25$

> " there is a linear decline in the mean of a trait with increasing f... if the allele associated with an increased value of the trait is dominant or partially dominant (ai ≥ di > 0)"

The mean will increase if the dominant allele produces a smaller phenotype. Here we say $A_1$ is now completely dominant,

$\bar{X}_{inbred} = \frac{(50 \cdot 5) + (0 \cdot 5) + (50 \cdot 10)}{100} = 7.5$

$\bar{X}_{outbred} = \frac{(25 \cdot 5) + (50 \cdot 5) + (25 \cdot 10)}{100} = 6.25$

*I hope that answers the question, I tried to answer last night but was too tired to think - this is just what I came up with on the walk to work today so I haven't had the time to check it/overthink it*

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. It is actually a very good "for dummies" explanation of a fairly complicated text. You answered so many of my questions this week. Thanks a lot!

Comment: haha - there's been a bit of activity to try and get the unanswered Q's reduced, there was a comment in the chat room that probably the only person to answer some of your unanswered Q's was me so I set myself the challenge of answering 5 this week... two to go! @remi.b